# making an Object Accessible globally without making a Global Variable

Tags: architecture, dependencies, global

I have some Object's which need to be accessed by some other Classes. i do not want to create a Global Variable. Dependency injection does not seem to be the right way of dealing with this, since one of the Objects i want to share is a config Object. Where do i Publish this objects without making them a Global Variable ?

i tried to create a Container Class (TManager) which holds the Objects that need to be accessed globally.
But i realized i need an instance of that manager Class too, where do i put the instance of that Manager Class ? Again the only thing that came to mind was making a Global Variable.

how do i avoid such cases ?

Comment: Maybe static variable?

Comment: @Thomas124124 i never used a static Variable. I use Lazarus in my Application. Isn't a Static Variable similar to a Global Variable ?

Comment: I suggest not discounting DI here. If you can create a singleton class (DI tooling may be able to help with that too), your config object can be contained in a singleton and provide the config object to where ever the singleton is injected. There may even be patterns in place for how to use DI with plain objects (I know of other frameworks that have this ability). It may be something to look into.